# How to avoid php.ini upload_max_filesize?

Tags: file-upload, plupload, upload-max-filesize

I am trying to upload a larger file than the upload_max_filesize configured in the php.ini
Is there any way to avoid the upload_max_filesize.
I am using plupload.js to upload files to Google Drive.

Comment: Which PHP version you are using?

Comment: Latest PHP version - v8.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `.user.ini` in your directory where upload script is located with following content.

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Here I am using 100M but you may not need that much.